# Pergunta marcada como "duplicada" entretanto sem uma resposta aceita

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

Caso o moderador julgue que a pergunta já foi respondida anteriormente, mesmo que não tenha sido a resposta correta, ele pode sinalizá-la como "duplicada"?

Acredito que isso leve o usuário a criar uma terceira, gerando mais problema ao SO.

Não seria mais correto aguardar a aprovação do próprio criador da pergunta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso geralmente não é a ação de um moderador, mas de usuários comuns da comunidade que votam para fechar a pergunta. Cinco votos são suficientes. No caso de um diamante votar (um moderador), o voto dele é decisivo.

Caso você não concorda com o fechamento, comente argumentando e edite a pergunta de forma a ficar claro que o fechamento foi inválido. Se foi fechada por duplicata, por exemplo, mencione na sua pergunta a pergunta anterior e explique a diferença e por que as respostas que estão lá não são suficientes para você. Duas perguntas são duplicatas se as respostas de uma respondem a outra e vice-versa.

Novamente, usuários podem votar para reabrir uma pergunta. Cinco votos anulam o fechamento.

---

Existe uma página sobre isso na central de ajuda: [**O que acontece se eu não concordar com a conclusão de uma pergunta? Como posso reabri-la?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

> 1. Deixar um comentário na própria pergunta pedindo a reabertura. **Explicar os detalhes**: explique por que a pergunta não deveria ter sido encerrada. **Seja construtivo**: o abuso verbal provavelmente afastará as pessoas em vez de ganhá-las para sua causa. Lembre-se de que qualquer um no site com uma reputação de 500 pontos pode votar pela reabertura da pergunta - mesmo que tenha sido encerrada por um moderador.
> 2. Não deixe de ler o aviso de encerramento e todos os comentários sobre a pergunta para poder resolver as preocupações levantadas. Resolver as preocupações normalmente significa **editar a publicação**, [o que qualquer usuário pode fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing).
> 3. Sinalizar a pergunta para chamar a atenção do moderador. Novamente, explique por que ela deveria ser reaberta. Há mais de um moderador e eles reconsideram as próprias decisões.
> 4. Se você tiver pelo menos 500 pontos de reputação, vote você mesmo para reabrir.

Answer (score 6):

Perguntas são marcadas como duplicadas se:

- Já existe uma pergunta com a resposta que você precisa; ou
- Você mesmo já fez a pergunta anteriormente, mesmo que não haja uma resposta aceita.

Isso ocorre por que se você mesmo perguntou você pode simplesmente **editar** a pergunta para torná-la mais clara / explicativa / atrativa, coisa que não é tão simples de fazer caso a pergunta tenha sido feita por outra pessoa.

Criar mais uma pergunta e abandonar a anterior (idêntica, ou quase) não é um comportamento desejado pois sua pergunta abandonada dificilmente terá uma resposta aceita e aumentará o índice de perguntas sem respostas. Além do mais, ficar criando mais e mais perguntas iguais dificilmente fará com que você tenha a resposta que você precisa se o conteúdo da pergunta (ou falta dele) que impediu que ela fosse devidamente respondida não for consertado.